# Read and extract XML parser?

Tags: c#, xml, batch-file

I have a folder which contains around 15,103 xml files.

An example of an xml file within the folder is the following.

[000010000.img.xml](http://www.privatepaste.com/1003dbac22)

A snippet of the xml part I want to focus in on.

```
<imgdir name="000010000.img">
   <imgdir name="info">
      <int name="version" value="10" />
      <int name="cloud" value="0" />
      <int name="town" value="0" />
      <float name="mobRate" value="1.0" />
      <string name="bgm" value="Bgm34/MapleLeaf" />
      <int name="returnMap" value="10000" />
      <string name="mapDesc" value="" />
      <int name="hideMinimap" value="0" />
      <int name="forcedReturn" value="999999999" />
      <int name="moveLimit" value="0" />
      <string name="mapMark" value="MushroomVillage" />
      <int name="swim" value="0" />
      <int name="fieldLimit" value="8260" />
      <int name="VRTop" value="-892" />
      <int name="VRLeft" value="-1064" />
      <int name="VRBottom" value="915" />
      <int name="VRRight" value="1334" />
      <int name="fly" value="0" />
      <int name="noMapCmd" value="0" />
      <string name="onFirstUserEnter" value="" />
      <string name="onUserEnter" value="go10000" />
      <int name="standAlone" value="0" />
      <int name="partyStandAlone" value="0" />
      <string name="fieldScript" value="" />
   </imgdir>

   </imgdir>
   <imgdir name="portal">
      <imgdir name="0">
         <string name="pn" value="sp" />
         <int name="pt" value="0" />
         <int name="x" value="-389" />
         <int name="y" value="183" />
         <int name="tm" value="999999999" />
         <string name="tn" value="" />
      </imgdir>
      <imgdir name="1">
         <string name="pn" value="sp" />
         <int name="pt" value="0" />
         <int name="x" value="-416" />
         <int name="y" value="185" />
         <int name="tm" value="999999999" />
         <string name="tn" value="" />
      </imgdir>
      <imgdir name="2">
         <string name="pn" value="sp" />
         <int name="pt" value="0" />
         <int name="x" value="-450" />
         <int name="y" value="183" />
         <int name="tm" value="999999999" />
         <string name="tn" value="" />
      </imgdir>
      <imgdir name="3">
         <string name="pn" value="out00" />
         <int name="pt" value="2" />
         <int name="x" value="1080" />
         <int name="y" value="541" />
         <int name="tm" value="20000" />
         <string name="tn" value="in00" />
         <string name="script" value="" />
         <int name="hideTooltip" value="0" />
         <int name="onlyOnce" value="0" />
         <int name="delay" value="0" />
      </imgdir>
   </imgdir>
```

I do not know how to code this (never done XML parsing before) and I think it may be possible to do in a .bat.

I need to automatically go into each XML file, extract all the portal information & map ID, and put it all into one text file.

Here is an example of how I need the output of the text to be (uses the snippet of XML above as a reference)

```
[10000] // <int name="returnMap" value="10000" />
total=4 // total amount of portals (4 below)
sp 0 -389 183 999999999 // <imgdir name="0">
sp 0 -416 185 999999999 // <imgdir name="1">
sp 0 -450 183 999999999 // <imgdir name="2">
out00 2 1080 541 20000 // <imgdir name="3">
```

I need a program to go into each xml, extract the information above and put it consistently into a single text file.

All XML files have the same structure and are all pretty much follow same style and imgdir name's, but all contain different amounts of portals.

Comment: You need to show some effort on your part, what have you tried to do and didn't work?

Comment: I just dont know how to grab "sp" & "out00" and also put it all into a while loop (like how would i move onto the next file and also at same time keep putting into same text).

Comment: Why not write a program, rather than trying to hack a .bat file? And if you insist on using a script, use PowerShell, which can do XML parsing

Comment: A batch file is going to be a nightmare, here, even if it's possible.  Since you have a C# tag, I'd definitely recommend that, instead.  Just have the program read the XML files and extract the data.  You can also have it reorganize the data however makes the most sense.  Failing that, as mentioned, PowerShell would be a good second choice.

Answer (score 1):

You should improve your searching ability, anyway I did a quick search and I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87274khy(v=vs.110).aspx that will help you with parsing XML, and this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzb96fk.aspx that will help you with iterating over directories and files.

Answer (score 0):

This type of problems are unpleasant to solve because you did *not* described the steps required to solve it, you just said "this is the data, this is the wanted result, solve it!". This means that you pass to us the task of correctly analyze the data and produce the right procedure to get the result...

The Batch file below is a way to solve this problem; I assumed that the parts after the `//` in the output example are not required.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for %%a in (*.xml) do call :processFile "%%a") > output.txt
goto :EOF


:processFile
set "returnMap="
for /F "tokens=3,5 delims==> " %%a in ('findstr /C:"<int name=" /C:"<imgdir name=" /C:"<string name=" %1') do (
   if not defined returnMap (
      if %%a equ "returnMap" (
         echo [%%~b]
         set returnMap=true
         set "portal="
      )
   ) else (
      if not defined portal (
         if %%a equ "portal" set portal=true & set /A i=0, skip=1
      ) else (
         if !skip! equ 1 (
            set /A skip-=1
            set "line="
         ) else if %%a neq "tn" (
            set "line=!line! %%~b"
         ) else (
            set /A i+=1, skip=1
            set "line[!i!]=!line:~1!"
            if %%b neq "" goto endPortals
         )
      )
   )
)
:endPortals
echo total=%i%
for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do echo !line[%%i]!
```

Output:

```
[10000]
total=4
sp 0 -389 183 999999999
sp 0 -416 185 999999999
sp 0 -450 183 999999999
out00 2 1080 541 20000
```

Comment: This was unexpected; holy hell, it's in batch script! I was currently coding and pretty much done a program in c# console, but I will just use this!

Comment: This did not work. I put the batch in the folder and let it run, this is an example of what was in output: http://www.privatepaste.com/8e05badfa1

Comment: The output in my answer was created processing the xml part you posted above. May the whole file have another `<int name="returnMap"` line before the posted one? If so, it may cause an error. I suggest you to run the program on the posted part first (in order to test that it is working correctly) and then run it over the whole file that have the same part.

Comment: The whole file is posted here; http://www.privatepaste.com/1003dbac22

I do not see any errors nor know what is wrong.

Comment: Did you run the program with the posted xml part? Did you got the same output I posted above? I'm sorry, but we need to start from a common point! I NOT downloaded your file and I will not do it, the file is too big!!!

Comment: I just ran with the snippet XML, here is the output!

http://www.privatepaste.com/56aa4d781e

Comment: This is strange. Although the Batch file have `@echo off` and `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` commands at beginning, when you process it the `@echo off` is cancelled before the first `call` and the Delayed Expansion was also cancelled at some point, as the last `for` command show. This should not happen and I have no idea why it happens in your case, but you may do a test for this. Delete all the lines below `:processFile` label and insert just these two: `set var=%1` and `echo File: !var!`. You will immediately detect if something is wrong with this 7-line file. What is your Win version?